# how to change variable in jsp using onclick method

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am trying to make a simple "TODO" list. I am able to create edit and delete task, but I want to make simple "set as done" or "set as TODO" feature. I would like to be able to click on "set as done" od "set as todo" button and that should automatically refresh my task.isDone field and display it in my TODO list (without refreshing page). 
I was trying to play with ajax, but have no idea how to use it here.

index.jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="manager" class="todo.TaskManager" scope="session"/>
....


<div class="title"> todo list</div>
        <% for (Task task : manager.getToDoList()) { %>
        <div class ="task_item">
            <p class = "task_name" ><%=task.getTaskName()%></p>
            <p class = "task_deadline"><%=task.getDeadline()%></p>
            <p class = "task_isDone"><%=task.getIsDone()%></p>
            <p>
                <% String button_value = task.getIsDone() ? "TODO" : "done"; %>
                <input type="button" value=<%=button_value%> onclick="change(this)" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <form method="post" action=<%="delete_process.jsp?task_name="+task.getTaskName()%>>
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
                </form>
            </p>
            <p>
                <form method="post" action=<%= "edit_task.jsp?task_name="+task.getTaskName()%>>
                    <input type="submit" value="Edit">
                </form> 
            </p>
        </div>
        <% }%>
        <a href="create_task.jsp">Create Task</A>
```

my change function:

```
function change(el){
    if ( el.value === "done" ){
        el.value = "TODO";
    }
    else {
        el.value = "done";
    }
    return $.ajax({
            url: 'index.jsp',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: {
               isDone: el.value
            }
        });    
    }
```

How to dynamically change task.isDone field and display it in my index.jsp? Could any one give me some tips about using ajax here?

Answer (score 0):

> You can't mix and match Client and server side code.

`task.getIsDone()` executes at server side whereas any javascript/jQuery will be executed at client side.

If you just want to change the content of a field in you page, you can use jQuery. Assign the field (div, span, etc..) an id and use

$`('#fieldId').val('Some value');`

Comment: The thing is that I want to change the value in my java array that stores my tasks ( in the future it will be a database). This value is displayed as a field in my page. [ task.getIsDone() ].

 So I would like to do something like that: 

Click on the button-> change task.isDone filed in my java array -> display newly changed data in my page field.